# JavaScript Nested Object data access

Tags: javascript, object, nested

[code I'm using to access data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIKlz.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvQAF.png)the picture includes country data from country rest API
currencies:
USD:
name: "United States dollar"
symbol: "$"

In this situation, the keyword USD is different for each country, in that case how to access that USD and properties inside it(name, symbol) through currencies property.
***let currencies = { usd: { name: ' ', symbol: ' ' } };***
I used this line to declare variable but this line will update usd for all the countries.

Comment: Where is the Picture ?

Comment: Question might be clear

Comment: `currencies["usd"]` this will give properties of usd.

Answer (score 0):

We didn't get a full example but I assume you have something like this. This might explain how to access these values

```js
const data = [
  {
    country: "United States",
    currencies: {
      usd: {
        name: "US Dollar",
        symbol: "$",
      },
    },
  },
  {
    country: "England",
    currencies: {
      usd: {
        name: "Sterling Pound",
        symbol: "£",
      },
    },
  },
  {
    country: "Germany",
    currencies: {
      usd: {
        name: "Euro",
        symbol: "€",
      },
    },
  },
];
```

First you need to get property you're trying to destructure, let's say the country you're trying to access is the US.

```js
const selectedCountryData = data.find((val) => val.country === "United States");
```

And then simply extract values by destructuring

```js
const { currencies: { usd:{ name, symbol } } } = selectedCountryData;
```

Answer (score 0):

bro if you have

```
data={
currencies:{ 
    usd: { name: 'a', symbol: 'b' }
},

}
```

need convert Objtect to an array

```
if need key use Object.keys(data.currencies )   //get usd 
if need value use Object.values(data.currencies )  //get [name:'a' , symbol:'b']
and if need all  use Object.entries(data.currencies);

//get 
[                                       
0:[usd]    
1:[name:'a' , symbol:'b']
]
```

then
if you want the value of name you can use

```
Object.value(data.currencies)[0].name;       //get a
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).